# Handling clike comments in Jison

Tags: jison

I'm writing a compiler of clike language in JS using Jison as an lexer/parser generator with angular frontend. I nearly got the result I expected, but there is one thing that is puzzling me - how to make Jison ignore comments (both `/* block */` and `// line`)?

Is there any easy way to achieve it? Keeping in mind that the comment can potentially be inserted in the middle of any statement/expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ignore comments the same way you ignore whitespace: with a lexer rule that has no action.

For example:

```
\s+                                   /* IGNORE */
"//".*                                /* IGNORE */
[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^/*][^*]*[*]+)*[/]   /* IGNORE */
```

The first line ignores whitespace. The second ignores single-line comments. And the third ignores block comments.

Comment: That's the idea! Although the block comment didn't work for me (im using .jison file format) it gave me a clue and I've found following regexp that does the job: `"/*"((\*+[^/*])|([^*]))*\**"*/"`

Comment: @Vees: Yep, there was a typo (the star after the close parenthesis was missing). Fixed. Thanks.